# Actualizar una tabla con el campo de otra tabla (DB2)

Tags: sql

Necesito actualizar una tabla con el campo de otra tabla para los datos posteriores al 5 de abril.

Estoy usando esta consulta, pero falla porque la fecha no puedo meterla ahí.

```
MERGE INTO a
USING b
ON b.cruceA=a.cruceB
WHEN MATCHED AND FECHA_CARGA>='2017-04-05'
THEN UPDATE SET a.campo1=b.campo2||a.campo3;
```

¿Cómo puedo especificar la fecha de manera correcta?

Comment: Has probado `DATE(FECHA_CARGA) = '2017-04-05'`?

Comment: También da error. Informe de error:
Error SQL: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -203, SQLSTATE: 42702, SQLERRMC: FECHA_CARGA

Comment: `FECHA_CARGA` como está definido? Timestamp?

Comment: Está definido como DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes convertir la fecha a date:

```
MERGE INTO a
USING b
ON b.cruceA=a.cruceB
WHEN MATCHED AND FECHA_CARGA>=DATE('2017-04-05')
THEN UPDATE SET a.campo1=b.campo2||a.campo3;
```

Comment: era eso y también indicar a que tabla pertenecía FECHA_CARGA. Muchas gracias